# How can I insert this equation?

Tags: math-mode

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{How can I insert it in a way it can be more elegant ?}



\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



    W=\int_{k \lt \Lambda} [D g][DA][D\psi][D\Phi] \mathbf{exp} \Bigg(i \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \bigg[\frac{m_p^2}2 R-\frac14 F_{\mu \nu}^a F^{a\mu \nu}+i\overline\psi^i \gamma^\mu D_\mu\psi^i+\big(\overline\psi_L^i V_{i j} \Phi \psi_R^j +\mathrm{h.c.}\big)-\vert D_\mu \Phi\vert^2 -V(\Phi)\bigg)\Bigg)



\end{document}
```

[image]

Why I can't have it in a better form, also why the at the bottom of the first integral I added \lt but it doesn't work ?

Comment: You haven't told TeX to switch to math mode (using `$`), so it gave an error message when it encountered `\int`.  Please read your error messages.  If you want this as a displayed equation, surround it with `\[` and `\]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is too wide for one line. If you open a bracket with `[` you need to close it with `]`. Since you have Roman summation indices `i` (as is usual) you need to distinguish them from the imaginary `i`, same thing for differential `d` *operators* which need to go upright. I prefer a `\mathcal{D}` for the path integrals but left your `[D...]` notation. So, to leading approximation you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
W=\int\limits_{k < \Lambda} 
[D g]\,[DA]\,[D\psi]\,[D\Phi] \exp \Biggl(
\mathrm{i}\, \int\! \mathrm{d}^4x\, 
\sqrt{-g}\, \biggl[\frac{M_\mathrm{P}^2}{2} R
-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu}^a F^{a\mu \nu}\\
+\mathrm{i}\,\overline\psi^i \gamma^\mu D_\mu\psi^i
+\big(\overline\psi_\mathrm{L}^i V_{i j} 
\Phi \psi_\mathrm{R}^j +\mathrm{h.c.}\big)
-\lvert D_\mu \Phi\rvert^2 -V(\Phi)\bigg]\Bigg)
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a more appealing version with inputs by Bernard and Mico (thanks!).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
W=\int\limits_{k < \Lambda} 
[D g]\,[DA]\,[D\psi]\,[D\Phi] \exp \Biggl(
\mathrm{i}\, \int\! \mathrm{d}^4x\, 
\sqrt{-g}\, \biggl[\frac{M_\mathrm{P}^2}{2} R
-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu}^a F^{a\mu \nu}\\[-1ex]
+\mathrm{i}\,\overline\psi^i \gamma^\mu D_\mu\psi^i
+\bigl(\overline\psi_\mathrm{L}^i V_{i j} 
\Phi \psi_\mathrm{R}^j +\mathrm{h.c.}\bigr)
-\lvert D_\mu \Phi\rvert^2 -V(\Phi)\biggr]\Biggr)
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that I changed the subscripts for left- and right chiral projections of spinors to upright L and R to distinguish them from leptons (which are not used here) and the curvature term `R`, which is used here.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a small negative vertical space between the two lines, and `\mfrac{1}{4}` rather than a display style fraction for a simple numerical coefficient.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! I'd agree on the negative distance but in physics it is usual to keep the `\frac{1}{4}` as it is here. (Usually it is written as `\frac{1}{2}\tr\bigl(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\bigr)` or just `F\wedge *F`.)

Comment: I understand, but in many cases it gives the same importance to a simple physically meaningless (I believe) coefficient as to a physical variable. Just try it to see (it's about 80% of displaystyle – nothing to see with textstyle fractions).

Comment: @Bernard This is one way to look at it. The other way is to observe that there is another fraction involving the Planck mass and it is not necessarily a good idea to wildly mix fraction sizes in a formula. But certainly there are many ways to improve this equation.

Comment: +1. Since you use `\Biggl(` and `\biggl(`, I would change `\bigg]\Bigg)` to `\biggr]\Biggr)`.

Comment: @Mico Absolutely, thanks!! I thought I had done that but apparently not.